# Text boxes only char save-reset box

Tags: javascript, html

i want to create 2 text boxes.I want to write something on  those  text boxes ,and save the value of each in an array or somewhere.There are only char characters.I have and reset to delete a value if it needs.I did a lot work,but it didn't worked.

```
AM: <input type="text" id="myText" value="GiveAm" size="10" id="myInput"> 
<button onclick="document.getElementById('myInput').value = ''">Reset</button>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Kataxwrisi</button>


<br>
Surname <input id='charInput' type="text" value="" size="10%">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Kataxwrisi</button>
</br>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myText").value = "Johnny Bravo";
}
function getChar(event){
if(event.which == null){
return String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
}else if(event.which !-0 && event.charCode != 0){
return String.fromCharCode(event.which);
}else{return null; }
}
document.getElementById('charInput').onkeypress= 
function(event){
var char =getChar(event || window.event)
if(!char) return false;
document.getElementById('keyData').innerHTML =char + "was clicked";
return true;
}
</script>
```

Comment: You have two IDs on your first input.

Comment: Where is the element 'keyData'? I don't see it in your snippet.

Comment: ouuuuuuups !copy paste mistake! i edit

Comment: When do you want to 'save' the value? There has to be at least one trigger for that to happen. Every time they type in the text box? When they click the reset button? When they click out of the text box?

Comment: i want the save button when they press enter for example

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you are trying to do here. But this is my best guess at a solution. When a user presses the 'enter' key in a text box, the current value of that text box is stored in an array.

```js
  var arrSavedValues = [];
  function setInputValue(argInputID, argNewValue) {
    document.getElementById(argInputID).value = argNewValue;
  }
  function saveValue(e){
    if(e.keyCode === 13){
      e.preventDefault();
      var caller = e.target || e.srcElement;
      arrSavedValues.push(caller.value);
      alert("Saved " + caller.value + " to arrSavedValues.");
    }
  }
```

```html
<div>
  <label>AM:</label>
  <input id="txtAM" type="text" value="GiveAm" size="10" onkeypress="saveValue(event)" />
  <button onclick="setInputValue('txtAM','')">Reset</button>
  <button onclick="setInputValue('txtAM','Johnny Bravo')">Kataxwrisi</button>
</div>
<div>
  <label>Surname:</label>
  <input id="txtSurname" type="text" value="" size="10" onkeypress="saveValue(event)" />
  <button onclick="setInputValue('txtSurname','Johnny Bravo')">Kataxwrisi</button>
</div>
```

Comment: i want to save everything i write on text boxes,not to show me the johny bravo.I use this name just to show an example

Comment: Am and surname should save together